# how to transfer encrypted files from one linux machine(client) over ftp and decrypt on other linux machine(server)

Tags: linux, encryption, ftp, file-transfer

I want to write a program(java) which takes a file as input ,encrypt it(using aes128) and send that encrypted file via ftp and the receiver receives it and decrypt using a key.
I'm a beginner and any help on how can it be done? 
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](http://tech-lead.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-with-aes.html) link for encrypting and decrypting your file,first you need to read file and pass contents to encrypt() and decrypt() methods,you can use simple socket server and client for transferring files.

Comment: thanks. i would like to know what libraries / tools are available to implement ftp in my project?

Comment: @m.pooja: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707816/ftp-client-server-model-for-file-transfer-in-java and http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/ftp-client-server-1250.aspx