# Getting the full InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I am working on a Web Server, I am stuck on the HTTP method PUT ... I currently can only bet 10 bytes of data from the client when he tries to upload a file, bellow is what I have so far.

```
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
OutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(path); 

int count = 0;

while (count < 10) {
  int b = stream.read();
  if (b == -1) break;

  fos.write(b);
  ++count;
}
fos.close();
```

Please tell me how I can get the as much input the client writes.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read an http input stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856195/how-to-read-an-http-input-stream)

Comment: Brian Roach it does not answer my question!

Comment: The tutorial that explains how to read from streams certainly does. As do numerous Qs already on SO. The fact that you've written code that explicitly limits your loop to read exactly 10 bytes then are asking how to read more than 10 bytes ... makes me think perhaps starting with a beginner's book on Java might also be a good idea.

Comment: If you think that's a stupid question why don't you answer it your self. Don't be so cocky. I clearly said "I currently can only get 10 bytes of data from the client" because that's the code I have written. What I want is to get all data till the client stops writing or making a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You limited it to 10 by your while loop using 10.  Since `stream.read()` returns -1 at the end of the stream, use that in the while loop as the control:

```
 int count = 0;
 int b = 0;
 while ((b=stream.read()) !=-1) 
 {
   fos.write(b);
   count++;
 }
```

Comment: It would be more complete if you removed the count variable on your answer I think.

Comment: I thought he might want it to know at the end how many bytes the file was.

Comment: Ok, nice, I just thought he used this only to check the first 10 bytes input number.

Comment: But what is the client is not writing more it will still be waiting for the next stream, how can I do so that when the client does a new line the stream will close the previous bytes to written to the file?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void receiveFile(InputStream is){
        //Set a really big filesize
        int filesize = 6022386;
        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize];

        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("fileReceived.txt");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos)){

            //Read till you get a -1 returned by is.read(....)
            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            current = bytesRead;

            do {
                bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current,
                        (mybytearray.length - current));
                if (bytesRead >= 0)
                    current += bytesRead;
            } while (bytesRead > -1);

            bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
            System.err.println("File not found.");
        } 
        catch (SecurityException se){
            System.err.println("A Security Issue Occurred.");
        } 
    }
```

Based on this one: [FTP client server model for file transfer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707816/ftp-client-server-model-for-file-transfer-in-java)