# Issue while downloading a file from a WEB FTP using Java?

Tags: java, apache, ftp

I have been having an issue while downloading a file from a Web Ftp through a Java program using Apache Commons Net.

Let's say I want to download this file : **webftp.vancouver.ca/opendata/bike_rack/BikeRackData.csv**
This is not a file you will be able to download via an HTTP request. I can do it with my browser because I'm using a FTP plugin.

It appears that the traditionnal way to retrieve files from a FTP server doesn't work with that particuliar type (**Web FTP**). I can establish the connection, but the file retrieval doesn't work as the file is empty.

The code I used (classic way to retrieve a file using Apache Commons) is the following :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory;

public class FTPDownload {

        final private FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        private String input;
        private String server;
        private String path;
        private String destination;
        private String fileName;

    public FTPDownload(String input, String destination) {
            this.input = input;
            this.destination = destination;
            if (input != null && input.contains("/")) {
                    String[] elts = input.split("/");
                    server = elts[0];
                    fileName = elts[elts.length - 1];
                    path = input.substring(server.length() - 1);
            } else {
                    server = input;
                    path = null;
            }
    }

    public FTPDownload(String server, String path, String destination) {
            this.server = server;
            this.path = path;
            this.destination = destination;
            if (path != null && path.contains("/")) {
                    String[] elts = path.split("/");
                    fileName = elts[elts.length - 1];
            }
    }

    public boolean retrieveFile() throws IOException {
            boolean error = false;
            ftp.connect(server);
            int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                    ftp.disconnect();
                    return false;
            }
            ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftp.enterRemotePassiveMode();
            File download = new File(destination + "/" + fileName);
            OutputStream outputStream;
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(download);
            ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(path.substring(0, path.length() - fileName.length()));
            ftp.setParserFactory(new DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory());
            String[] list = ftp.listNames();
            ftp.retrieveFile(fileName, outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
            ftp.logout();
            return error;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
            FTPDownload myFtp = new FTPDownload("webftp.vancouver.ca", "/opendata/bike_rack/BikeRackData.csv", "E:\\test");
            myFtp.retrieveFile();

    }
```

}

Hope the problem is understandable.
Thank you.

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FTP client server model for file transfer in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707816/ftp-client-server-model-for-file-transfer-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please check these links to learn [How to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's also possible that you misunderstand, what FTP is. Do you really want to use FTP protocol? Or do you want to download the file from a webpage using HTTP protocol, like a web browser does?

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I don't misunderstand, the file is not a web page, but a real file inside an FTP server.
The only way I can access this file is trhough its URL (that's why I call it a web FTP).
If you try to download it as is with a classic browser, it will fail because of the protocol. You will need to install a FTP plugin to retrieve the file.

You can test it with this file : 
webftp.vancouver.ca/opendata/bike_rack/BikeRackData.csv

Comment: So as Teocci already suggested, show us [mcve]. No methods, constructors, fancy path parsing. Just a simple code that connects to a fixed hostname, downloads a single fixed file to a fixed local destination.

Comment: Also show us a log file from a standalone FTP client, showing a download of the same file.